# How to process uploaded file without saving in Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor

I want to upload a CSV in a meteor application and pre-process the file before saving.  In fact, I don't need to save the file, I only want to derive collection entries and insert non-duplicates.

Is there any way in Meteor to access and process the text associated with an uploaded file without saving it?

Comment: You might want to process the CSV file on the browser-side, and then run the Mongo.insert()s from the browser on the result-set.  Here is an atmosphere module [`eaftc:html5csv`](https://atmospherejs.com/eaftc/html5csv) I wrote for browser-side CSV data manipulation.  It can do file "uploads" into an Array of Arrays in browser memory of a user-selected CSV file if the CSV isn't too large.  The module is not Meteor-specific, so you'll still have to write the deduping/conversion/Mongo-insertion parts while it can handle data collection of file from user.

Comment: I'd love to use your module... problem is it's not really a "csv" in the final format I want to process.  It's a csv in the format of a third party vendor that requires a lot of pre-processing.  Are there some hooks I can look at in your code to glean what I need to get the data when I need it?  And if so, any idea what the size limitations might be?

Comment: As the license is GPL, why not search through the code on github and find the part that you don't know... i.e. perhaps how to read a user-selected file in Javascript on the browser.   There are also Stack Overflow answers for that too, which is how this library got started...  Also read [MDN FileReader Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Comment: It can do at least 200,000 cells (2000 rows of a 100 column table) on a desktop, but it won't be snappy filtering and plotting that kind of data. Mobile / tablets vary.

Comment: ugh... http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader  IE...  No server-side alternatives to intercept the file pre-write?

Comment: Yeah if you want to support old stuff there could be issues.  Not sure if IE has an alternative to filereader, IE *eventually* had an alternative way to export JS data as a file (basically like a "fake download") while Chrome and FF had it earlier.